# Client-side Required error message not showing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, data-annotations, requiredfieldvalidator

I want to implement client side validation on my form, but none of the required error message is showing when I not putting data.
Scripts are loaded correctly in the layout file.
And in the rest of the views, Required messages are displayed correctly and the program works correctly .
I've sent the codes for this subject to the attachment.

controller:

```html
  <HttpPost()>
        Function GalleryFiles1(ByVal docs As MachininfoDocs, ByVal imgUp As HttpPostedFileBase) As ActionResult
            If ModelState.IsValid Then
                If imgUp IsNot Nothing And IsImage(imgUp) Then
                    docs.FileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() & Path.GetExtension(imgUp.FileName)
                    docs.DocGroup = 1
                    docs.MachininfoID = PVMachinInfoId

                    imgUp.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/Images/MachinImages/" & docs.FileName))
                    Dim img As New ImageResizer()
                    img.Resize(Server.MapPath("/Images/MachinImages/" & docs.FileName), Server.MapPath("/Images/MachinImages/Thumb/" & docs.FileName))
                    db.MachininfoDocs.Add(docs)
                    db.SaveChanges()
                End If
            End If
            Return RedirectToAction("GalleryFiles1", New With {Key .id = docs.MachininfoID})
        End Function
```

View:

```html
@ModelType Machinary.MachininfoDocs
@Code
    ViewData("Title") = "اسناد مالکیت"
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.vbhtml"
End Code

@Using (Html.BeginForm("GalleryFiles1", "Machininfo", FormMethod.Post, New With {.enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(Function(model) model.MachininfoID)

    @<div Class="panel">

        <header Class="panel-heading tab-bg-dark-navy-blue">
            <Label Class="bg-transparent wht-color"> اطلاعات جامع ماشین آلات- اسناد مالکیت</Label>
        </header>
        <br />

        <div Class="form-horizontal panel-body">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.ValidationSummary(True, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.Title, htmlAttributes:=New With {.class = "control-label col-md-2"})
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.Title, New With {.htmlAttributes = New With {.class = "form-control"}})
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.Title, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.FileName, htmlAttributes:=New With {.class = "control-label col-md-2"})
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input type="file" name="imgUp" class="form-control-file" />
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.FileName, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="ثبت" class="btn btn-success" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                @code
                    Dim al As List(Of MachininfoDocs) = ViewBag.Docs
                End code
                <Table Class="table table-bordered table-responsive-sm">
                    <tr>
                        <th class="col-md-3"> تصویر</th>
                        <th class="col-md-7"> عنوان</th>
                        <th>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    @For Each item In al
                        @<tr id="tbrow_@(item.Id)">
                            <td>
                                <img style="width:100% ; height:120px" src="~/Images/MachinImages/Thumb/@item.FileName" class=" img-thumbnail" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @item.Title
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="DeleteTbRow(@item.Id)">
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash btn btn-danger btn-sm"></i>
                                </a>

                            </td>

                        </tr>
                    Next

                </Table>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
End Using

<div class="pull-left btn btn-default">
    @Html.ActionLink("برگشت به لیست", "Index")
</div>

@section MyScripts
<script>
    function DeleteTbRow(id) {
        if (confirm('آیا از حذف مطمئن هستید ؟')) {
            $.get("/Machininfo/DeleteGallery/" + id,
                function () {
                    $("#tbrow_" + id).hide('slow');
                });
        }
    }
</script>
End Section
```

MetaData class:

```html
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
Friend Class MachininfoDocsMetaData
    <ScaffoldColumn(False)>
    <Bindable(False)>
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property MachininfoID As Integer
    Public Property DocGroup As Integer

    <Required(AllowEmptyStrings:=False, ErrorMessage:="لطفاً {0} را به درستی درج نمائید")>
    <DisplayName("عنوان")>
    <Display(Name:="عنوان")>
    <StringLength(200, ErrorMessage:="مقدار {0} نباید بیش از 200 کاراکتر باشد")>
    Public Property Title As String

    <DisplayName("انتخاب فایل")>
    <Display(Name:="انتخاب فایل")>
    Public Property FileName As String

End Class
<MetadataType(GetType(MachininfoDocsMetaData))>
Partial Public Class MachininfoDocs

End Class
```

Comment: did you check for any client side script error or conflict for jQuery? I had same problem for this reason.

Comment: In other views, the program correctly displays errors. Not displaying on this page

Answer (score 0):

One common mistake is for who use mvc default bundles forget to import the bundle in the layout

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

Also you should activate them in the web.config appsettings

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="none" />
```

Comment: In other views, the program correctly displays errors. Not displaying on this page